# Compile Stylus (nodejs) .styl file to 2 different css files (Mobile and Desktop)

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

Is it possible to compile a single stylus file to into 2 different css files, e.g. for ipad web app I am not interested in the -moz etc css online webkit, so one is optimised for mobile and the other for cross-browser app?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the short answer is that given a single `.styl` file, you will output a single corresponding `.css` file. However, there are ways to achieve your goal. You could use [CSS3 media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) and have the same stylesheet produce alternate styles depending on the screen size.  Secondly, you could use an `@import` statement to achieve almost what you need by doing something like this

In `shared.styl`

```
//Put your default shared styles here
```

In `screen.styl`

```
@import "shared"
//Put your desktop web app overrides here
```

and in `mobile.styl`

```
@import "shared"
//put your mobile optimized overrides here
```

Comment: thanks Peter. I do something like this already, what I've decided to do is use stylus as if targeting the desktop and then write a simple node script to parse the css file and delete any non -webkit prefixes and save that as my mobile version. its a bit of a hack but will work for me for now.

Comment: How do you get stylus to compile anything other than style.css?